# PHP Find if any character of a string is not in ISO 8859-1

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I'm facing a problem checking for encodes. I know encodes are a mess and are hard to check.

I went to a lot of options and I finally ended up trying preg_match.

I need to detect if any character is not a valid ASCII or ISO 8859-1 (latin1 in mysql).

I ended up with this:

```
return 0 === preg_match('/[^\x00-\x7F\xA2-\xFF]+/', $value);
```

But does not work with this table:

`¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬-®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ`

Some of this characters are not valid latin, but they are in the latin charset. Like É or À
I guess is because my locale or the internal function of the encondigs is set to UTF8.

Because this `ʧ` evaluates as a valid latin character. Even when is not in the charset http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1

Any help here is much appreciated.

NOTE:

I also made a lot of tests with  `mb_detect_encoding, mb_check_encoding, mb_convert_encoding and iconv` but all of them return ʧ as a valid latin1 character.

I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Looked a bit into just checking errors on converting to ISO-8859-1, but PHP seems to be notoriously loose in how it converts and what happens on errors.

Comment: PHP doesn't see the "picture" of the character. It just sees the underlying number representingt that code. Since 8859-1 is an 8bit charset and has characters for all 256 chars, **ANY** 8bit number is valid in 8859. The picture of it may be some completely random garbage, but it'll be "valid" 8859-1

Comment: Using the [_u_ pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) should do the trick.

Comment: @MarcB that makes totally sense. I didn't think of it in the point of view where all 8bit chars are valid iso even if they are not the char I was thinking of...

Now I can understand "weird" (for me) behaviours when checking encodings.

Comment: @nwellnhof u modifier works but is tricky because it changes based on the locale set, taking in care I don't own this kind of configurations it may be a risk to expose that.

Comment: @nax: yep. a high-bit utf8 char, say some 3- or 4-byte foreign character in an obscure language would be valid 8859, because each of those bytes is available in 8859. it'll be 3  or 4 characters of 8859, and look like garbage, but it'd still be "valid".